# Problema con un ciclo de números aleatorios: Java

Tags: java, bucles, random

Tengo el siguiente problema:

El ejercicio es el típico juego de "frio-caliente", el usuario debe de pensar en un número y la máquina le imprime un número aleatorio entre 1 y 100, luego le preguntara si el número esta por encima, por debajo o si es el correcto.

Si el número estab por debajo, debe de mostrarle un número aleatorio entre 1 y el número aleatorio anterior.

Si está por encima debe de ser un número en el rango del número aleatorio a 100 y si es el correcto el ciclo se rompe.

**Código**

```
import java.util.*;

public class HighLowGameBlackbelt {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

                Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
                String HumanAnswer = "";
                int ComputerGuess = 0;
                Random rd = new Random();
                ComputerGuess = rd.nextInt(100)+1;
                System.out.println("Hello, Whats Your Name?");
                String Name = input.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Niice to meet you " + Name+ ", Do you want to play a game?");
                String answer = input.nextLine();
                String StartGame = "Yes";
                boolean equal1 =  answer.equalsIgnoreCase(StartGame);

                if (equal1 == true) {

                        System.out.println("The rules are these: you have to think in a number between 1 and 100");
                        System.out.println("I'll try to guess, if the answer is too High you have to input H");
                        System.out.println("If it is too low you have to input l");
                        System.out.println("If it is  right, you have to inpu R");
                        System.out.println("I'll start");
                        String Breakcycle = "R";
                        boolean EndComand = false;
                        int Counter= 0;
                        int LastRandom =0;

                        while(!EndComand) {
                                System.out.println("Your number is: "+ ComputerGuess);
                                System.out.println("too (h)igh, too (l)ow, or (r)ight?");
                                HumanAnswer = input.nextLine();
                                LastRandom = ComputerGuess;
                                if(HumanAnswer == "H" &&    HumanAnswer == "h") {
                                        ComputerGuess = rd.nextInt(LastRandom-1)-1;
                                }else {
                                        if (HumanAnswer == "L"&& HumanAnswer == "l") {
                                                ComputerGuess = rd.nextInt(LastRandom)+1;
                                        }else {
                                                if (HumanAnswer == "R"&& HumanAnswer == "r"){
                                                        EndComand =true;
                                                }
                                                Counter ++;
                                        }
                                }
                        }

                        System.out.println("Yeah, I got it");
                        System.out.println ("It only took me: " + Counter+ " rounds");
                        System.out.println ("See you next time");

                } else {

                        System.out.println("Ok, see you next Time :)");

                }

        }
}
```

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el problema?¿qué es lo que hace el código que muestras?

Comment: Se queda pegado en la primer parte del ciclo. Solamente imprime el primer número al azar.

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que estas usando la condicion && que es un and, deberias usar || que seria un or

Comment: Holaaa, acabo de intentar hacer el cambio, pero sigue sucediendo lo mismo. Se queda congelado en el primer número aleatorio

Comment: Utiliza el metodo HumanAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase("H") en vez del operador ==

Comment: Gracias! eso funciono.

Comment: @Andres trata de añadir el código de forma cambia `esteCodigo` a `esteNuevoCodigo` y el porqué y de esta forma queda para futuros usuarios que puedan tener un caso afín a este. @Ethan, si la respuesta de @Andres te ha servido para resolver el problema podrías marcarla como válida. Saludos a ambos.

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/232168)

Comment: @JorgeGuz explícame por que esto no provee una respuesta a a la pregunta.

Comment: @Gabitohh se trata de un comentario, que puede ayudar a solucionar el problema, eso no se discute en este caso, pero que no cumple los estándares de SO para considerarse una respuesta.